# What does length_3d(point) actually calculate using GPS data?

Tags: math, 3d, gps, coordinates, distance

I have been trying to calculate the most accurate distance of my tracks using Haversine 2D distance calculation and stumbled upon the function length_3d in the link below. It uses latitude, longitude and altitude to calculate the 3D distance, which is probably the better option. But how does it do so? I can not find formulas relating to this function at all.

link: https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/dev/gpxpy/gpx.py

Comment: Follow the code trail? Github lets you click through to function definitions; at some point you hit `location.distance_3d` so you search the repo and you find https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/eaa019f7479daced7e9480343f8d22c439655b70/gpxpy/geo.py#L345, then you keep clicking through. You'll eventually make it to `def haversine_distance`.

Comment: Yes i tried to do that, but haversine uses 2D coordinates which confuses me again. Someone on StackO has mentioned the Pythagorean Formula (distance_3d = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)**0.5) before but it doesn't yield the same result as the length function, which confuses me further.

Comment: No, of course not: the surface of a sphere is not a flat plane, you can't use Euclidean distance. For distances on (or above) a sphere you need to work with the math used for great circles. Everything is (co)sines and arc(co)sines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula explains this just fine. It might _look_ intimidating, but when you actually just read the text, there's nothing beyond high school trigonometry in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that definitely makes more sense.  But sorry, I'm still a bit confused as the spherical distance works with latitude and longitude and the length_3d function works three-dimensional, which is why i asked which formula it was based on. How can the altitude be incorporated in the haversine calculation method? Sorry again and thank you!

Comment: Not sure how much heavy lifting the word "can" is doing there, because the answer to that is "that depends on what path through the sky you're taking". There is no "one" length. Draw the great circle segment with the radius of Earth that connects your two coordinates (ignoring altitude). Then draw another circle segment with a radius `radius of Earth + alt1` above that, and then draw a third circle segment with a radius `radius of Earth + alt2`. If you don't need military precision (literally) then you simply compute the distances for both the alt1 and alt2 circle segments, and average them.

Comment: So look at the code to see what path we're taking through the sky: https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/2c76d82ad2371ecfd79b00b010ad1f4767ee6b87/gpxpy/geo.py#L197-L224 takes the "distances without taking elevation into account", then takes the difference in elevation, and computes the euclidean distance using those two numbers. While this means that the path through the sky is actually concave with respect to the ground, and isn't the shortest possible path, it's still a valid length measurement.